# Tkinter, saving functions to a list and then running them

Tags: python, list, user-interface, listbox, tkinter

I'm working on a GUI for a project in school. All the buttons that I have in my GUI are bound with functions that I have created. These functions call for already predefined functions. For some of the predefined functions, I need one or two arguments and I have solved that with entries. I type in the arguments in the right entries that are connected to the specific button and when I press the button, the function will run with the corresponding arguments.

The thing I want to do is to in some way when I press a button, the function should be saved to a list instead of being executed right away. And when I push the "run" button(a new button that I will create) everything in my list will be executed. I have been thinking about using a list box but I don't know exactly how they work or if its even possible to run a list box that contains a number of functions. Does someone have any ideas or solutions for me? Can I use the list box for this or is there something else that is better to use?

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.entry1 = IntVar()
        self.entry2 = IntVar()

        def do_something():
             value1 = self.entry1.get()
             value2 = self.entry2.get()
             self.listbox.insert(END, "predefined_function(value1, value2)")

        def run_listbox_contents():
             pass

        self.button = Button(frame, text="Move", command=lambda: do_something())
        self.button.pack(side=TOP)

        self.entry1.set("value1")
        self.entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.entry1)
        self.entry.pack(side=TOP)

        self.entry2.set("value2")
        self.entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.entry2)
        self.entry.pack(side=TOP)

        self.listbox = Listbox(master)
        self.listbox.pack(side=TOP)


root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.title("Mindstorms GUI")
root.geometry("800x1200")

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't want to save *functions* to a list. I would suggest another solution for you.

I suppose you have heard of the principle of **MVC (Model-View-Controller)**. In your case, the list box is a part of **view**, and the process that saves functions and then calls them at once is a part of **controller**. **Separate them.**

You might want to save and display any string in the list box to let the users know that the corresponding functions have been enlisted and ready to run. For example, save a **string** `"Function1 aug1 aug2 aug3"` or `"Funtion2 aug1 aug2"` or whatever you like **as a handle of the corresponding function**.

And for the controller part, write a function (let's say `conductor()`). It **reads** the handle strings from the list, **parses** them and **calls** the corresponding functions. Where you want to run the enlisted functions, there you just call `conductor()`.

---

**Update:**

Due to your comment I understand that you are pretty new to program. Let me show you how to write a simplest parser with your given variable names.

```
def run_listbox():
    to_do_list = #get the list of strings
    for handle_string in to_do_list:
        #Let's say you got 
        #handle_string = "Predfined_function1 value1 value2" 
        #by here
        handle = handle_string.split(" ")
        #Split the string by space, so you got 
        #handle = ["Predfined_function1", "value1", "value2"] 
        #by here
        if handle[0] == "Predfined_function1":
            Predfined_function1(handle[1], handle[2]) #Call Predfined_function1(value1, value2)
        elif handle[0] == "Predfined_function2":
            Predfined_function2(handle[1], handle[2])
        #elif ...
        #...
        #elif ...
        #...
        #elif ...
        #...
```

This is not a perfect parser, but I hope it could let you know what does a parser look like.

Comment: Since I am completely new to programming, MVC is not something that I have heard of before. But I think I understand it and what you mean. Lets say that I save "Predfined_function value1 value 2" as a string to the list box and I will use the function run_listbox(). What do I have to write so that the function parses all my strings and then calls them(in this case Predfined_function(value1, value2)? Since Im new to programming, I dont think I have encountered parsing yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I have one final question, and its about handle_string = "Predefined_function1 value1 value2". If I have three strings in my list box, like "Predefined_function1 value1 value2", "Predfined_function2 value1" and "Predefined_function3(this one does not need an argument). What do I have to write so that each of my string in the list box are known as a handle_string? Do I just write that handle_string = ""(a string in general), or do I do it in another way? Hope you understand what Im asking about.

Comment: @user3067156 Do you see the `for` loop? It assigns each of the strings to `handle_string` one by one.

Comment: Yes I did, but I thought that I needed to write somewhere that the strings in my list box are handle_strings. I guess I dont have to write that now that I look at it again. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Isn't every string in the list box handle_strings? Is there any other string in the box?

Comment: Yes they are, I just read it wrong and didnt realize that each of the strings are assigned to handle_string.

Comment: I have accepted but I dont have enough reputation to upvote something, haha :) I have encountered one final(I hope) problem. So the value1, value2 and so on are integers. When I type in two numbers for them in the corresponding entries and then click the button for that function, I get the function name and the names value1 and value2 in my listbox. Instead I want the numbers I typed in for the two values to be displayed in the listbox after the function. I also get an error message saying 'Bad operand type for abs(): 'str' when I run the listbox. Is this because my two values are integers?

Comment: because the two values are string. use `x = int(x)` to convert `x` into an integer and then do `abs(x)`. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried that in a few ways but I cant seem to get it to work. One of my arguments are called 'power' in a few of the predefined functions, and I dont know it thats also causing an error because in the error message there is also something mentioned about '_power' and 'pw=abs(power)'. Haha sorry for being so troublesome :(

Answer (score 1):

Just use a standard list.

something like this

```
def hest(txt):
    print "hest: " +txt

def horse(txt):
    print "horse: " + txt

funcList = []

funcList.append(hest)    
funcList.append(horse)    

for x in funcList:
    x("Wow")
```

This outputs

```
hest: Wow
horse: Wow
```

Was this what you wanted?